# How to retrieve particular data from xml file using c#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

As a part of functional testing of my Api, I want to scrap the "body" part of given xml using C#. How can I do that?

This is my xml file

```
<Root>
  <collection>  </collection>
  <run>
      <stats>  </stats>
      <execution>
         <cursor>   </cursor>
         <response>
             <body> Some Values here </body>
         </response>
      </execution>
  </run>
</Root>
```

Comment: You can use XPath or maybe try to deserailize this data into .net objects. XPath link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: What does scrap the body mean?  Delete it?  Bad data in the value?  What?

Answer (score 1):

First Load the Your xml in XmlDocument object and than using `GetElementsByTagName("body")` you can get the Node say body

```
XmlDocument _LocalInfo_Xml = new XmlDocument();
_LocalInfo_Xml.Load(_LocalInfo_Path);
XmlElement _XmlElement;
_XmlElement = _LocalInfo_Xml.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0] as XmlElement; 
string Value = _XmlElement.InnerText;
```

Now Value contains you body text that is

> Some Values here